# Why can a read only property be assigned via constructor?

Tags: c#

I've set property `Name` is read only, but it can still be assigned.

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public Person(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
    }
}
```

Try to set value to property `Name`:

```
var p = new Person("Kevin");            
Console.WriteLine(p.Name); //output: Kevin
p.Name = "John"; //Property or indexer 'Person.Name' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
```

Can you explain me why?

Comment: Because its allowed by the C#6 "standard". You can initialize a ReadOnly property in the constructor or during object construction, but not after the object is constructed. This is new for C#6.

Comment: @RonBeyer: No, that's not equivalent. That will use a read/write field, and you'll be able to use the property setter anywhere in the type rather than only in the constructor, and the setter will be exposed via reflection. Note that a read-only property *cannot* be used in an object initializer.

Comment: @JonSkeet I removed it after I wrote it and realized it was wrong, I remembered that it was more equivalent to a `readonly` field, not a property.

Comment: @RonBeyer: Okay. I'd remove the bit about "during object constructor" - it really is *only* assignable as part of the property initializer or in the constructor. It can't be used in an object initializer, nor during another method *called* by the constructor.

Comment: @JonSkeet You'll have to leave your comment up, too late to edit mine, I usually don't use "initializer" functions so I forgot about the *"method called by the constructor"* part, but its a good note to have because that part can be confusing.

Comment: @JonSkeet Just for clarification, in C# 6 could you do something like `var x = new MyObject(){ Name = "sab669" };` where name is defined as it is in HappyCoding's question? Or are you saying that is what is not allowed?

Comment: @sab669: No, that's not allowed. Because that translates to code that constructs an object and then assigns a value to the property - and that's not valid with a read-only property.

Comment: Ok, I didn't think it was valid but I wasn't sure if I was understanding you two correctly. Thanks.

Comment: Why the hell this has been downvoted ? I bumped on this case today then I am very happy to see an answer here. This new "feature" of C# 6.0 that has not been advertised a lot and it deserve attention.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It can *only* be assigned in the constructor or in the initializer for the property declaration - just like a read-only field can only be assigned in the constructor or in the field initializer.

There won't be a property setter generated - the compiler will use a read-only field, and initialize it in the constructor. So the generated code will be broadly equivalent to:

```
class Person
{
    private readonly string _name;

    // Old school: public string Name { get { return _name; } }
    public string Name => _name; 

    public Person(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }
}
```

It's *enormously* useful to be able to do this, and I'm really glad it was added to C# 6.